# Proof that in the family of sets $A_t = (\frac{t}{2} ; \frac{t+1}{2})$ for $t \in (0;1)$, $\bigcup A_{t} = (0;1)$, $\bigcap A_{t} = \{\frac{1}{2}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As in the title, I have to proof that for the family of sets given as: $A_t = (\frac{t}{2} ; \frac{t+1}{2})$ for $t \in (0;1)$:

- $\bigcup\limits_{t \in (0;1)} A_{t} = (0;1)$
- $\bigcap\limits_{t \in (0;1)} A_{t} = \{\frac{1}{2}\}$

I don't know how to do the proof form right to left. I mean proving that for every $x$ there is $t$ that represents a set that includes $x$. Usually I would use Archimedes' Axiom but out here I have no natural numbers. How then prove that for x close to 0 there is a set with a boundary that is even closer to 0? I need to do it "in the way of set theory" - I mean that I can not use boundary-value analysis nor function analysis.

Comment: You're looking for $ t $ such that $ x \in \left( \frac{t}{2}, \frac{t+1}{2} \right) $.  That means you need $ \frac{t}{2} < x < \frac{t+1}{2} $.  You can't find any $ t $ that satisfy this inequality?

Comment: I recommend you back up for a minute and stop thinking about formal proofs and "Archimedes' Axiom", and return to the basics.  Draw a picture of the sets $ A_t $.  What do they look like?  Build up an ironclad intuition as to what their union and intersection ought to be.  I don't even like this problem, because I don't like that they gave you the answer.  It should have simply asked you to compute $ \cup A_t $ and $ \cap A_t $.

Comment: Yeah, I see those sets I know that their union can't reach 0 nor 1 but can be as near as a real number can be to a natural number. However I got no idea how to write a formal proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to prove the first equality with double inclusions:

since for every $t\in(0,1)$ one has $0<\frac t2<\frac{t+1}2<1$, it follows that $A_t\subset(0,1)$ for all such $t$, hence $\bigcup_{t\in(0,1)}A_t\subseteq(0,1)$.

Conversely take any $x\in(0,1)$ and search for some $t\in(0,1)$ such that $x\in A_t$, that is $\frac t2<x<\frac{t+1}2$; you'll see that $t=2x-\frac12$ will work. Hence $x\in\bigcup_{t\in(0,1)}A_t$ so you conclude that $(0,1)\subseteq
\bigcup_{t\in(0,1)}A_t$ and we are done with the first one.

Second one: we want to study $\bigcap_{t\in(0,1)}A_t$, that is we search for the elements $x$ belonging to $A_t$ for all $t\in(0,1)$:
\begin{align*}
x\in A_t\;\forall t\in(0,1)\;
&\Longleftrightarrow\frac t2<x<\frac{t+1}2\;\;\forall t\in(0,1)\\
\end{align*}
you can see that $x=1/2$ is satisfies this condition, that is
$$
\left\{\frac12\right\}\subseteq\bigcap_{t\in(0,1)}A_t$$
Moreover for every $x<1/2$ or $x>1/2$ you can find some $t\in(0,1)$ such that the last two equality are not simultaneously satisfied, from which the last inclusion is indeed an equality.

Comment: You probably mean $t = x - \frac{1}{2}$ nad not $t = x + \frac{1}{2}$, am I right?

Comment: @theboyboy: yes I have edited